# Azure Create Database In Code

Tags: sql, mongodb, azure

I have a prototype paas (platform as a service). The solution currently saves data for all customers in a single sql instance. For now this is fine, but I worry about slowdowns when the db grows. I reason I could keep the service running fast if each customer had their own database.

I was looking on the Azure portal and I found nothing. I can easily create a new database manually - but - I don't want that, I want to keep everything automated. Is there a way I can setup a sql server 'group' ?

While I am at it, SQL is not a requirement. My data is noSQL ready. Is this something I could do with monogoDB running on a worker role ? me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Azure SQL Managment Nuget

http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Sql

http://www.bradygaster.com/post/managing-windows-azure-sql-databases-using-the-management-libraries-for-net

Answer (score 2):

You should look at the [Azure DocumentDb](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/documentdb/) preview, which is a NoSQL database provided as a managed service.

Comment: DocumentDB has two problems. 1) No sorting. 2) Azure only. I want something that I can move to a dedicated of AWS.